# Objective-c function pointer

Tags: objective-c, function, pointers

I need to do a thing like this:

```
id myFunction = aMethodDeclaredInMyClass;

[self myFunction]
```

any help is appreciated!

Comment: See selectors in Objective-C. First results in google give you everything you need.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you know the method in advance:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(myMethod) withObject:nil];
```

If you don't know the method name in advance:

```
SEL selector = NSSelectorFromString(someSelectorStringYoureGiven);
[self performSelector:selector withObject:nil];
```

Both these examples assume your function accepts no arguments, nor requires execution on a different thread, nor requires delayed execution. There are many variants for all combinations of those conditions (and NSInvocation for even more complex cases). Search `performSelector` in xcode's documentation to see all the variants.

Comment: perfect:

`SEL myAction = nil;
.. some stuff ..
myAction = @selector(actionWalk);
.. some stuff ..
[self performSelector:myAction];`

thank you @Jarret Hardie

Answer (score 3):

My guess is you want;

```
[self performSelector:@selector(aMethodDeclaredInMyClass)]
```

Read the docs on dynamic dispatch;

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocSelectors.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH23-SW1

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008048

Answer (score 0):

Also see [`objc_msgSend()`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Articles/ocrtHowMessagingWorks.html). You'd set up a `SEL` selector variable.

Comment: You almost never want to be messing around with `objc_msgSend` directly. It's like swatting flies with a broadsword. There are cases where you want to use it, but they are very special.

Comment: Isn't `objc_msgSend()` more or less the same as `-performSelector:withObject:`, but with less overhead? (Genuinely curious.)

Comment: @Alex Reynolds: To a certain degree. The thing is that `objc_msgSend` is more flexible and easier to misuse without realizing it, so using it directly is kind of a bad habit to get into. My phrasing might have been a little sharp, but I don't want to see innocent Googlezens shooting themselves in the foot unnecessarily.

Comment: Do you have examples of how it might be misused? Now I'm really curious. I had no idea it is considered verboten.

Comment: @Alex Reynolds: What about the cases wherein `objc_msgSend_stret` would be more appropriate? If you start considering these corner cases, you might have defeated the purpose of using Obj-C in the first place. :)

Comment: If you have ever called objc_msgSend() directly for a method that takes an argument, you are using objc_msgSend() wrong...  Technically, even with a method that takes no args, directly using objc_msgSend() is wrong (but it happens to "just work" on pretty much all architectures).